# Vite manifest not found after changing outDir in vite.config.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

When I changed `outDir: "public"` to laravel 9.41, throwing an error.

> Vite manifest not found at:
> E:\oblia\obilia_site\public\build/manifest.json

Why is Vite looking for manifest in the build directory when I changed it to public? The app is running fine when I am running `npm run dev`, but when is stop dev and ran `npm run build`, I get this error. I want all my assets to be in public, not in public/build.

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { viteStaticCopy } from "vite-plugin-static-copy";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
  base: "/",
  build: {
    outDir: "public",
    emptyOutDir: false,
  },

  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: [
        "resources/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "resources/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "resources/css/feather.css",
        "resources/css/owl.carousel.min.css",
        "resources/css/magnific-popup.min.css",
        "resources/css/lc_lightbox.css",
        "resources/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
        "resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css",
        "resources/css/select.bootstrap5.min.css",
        "resources/css/dropzone.css",
        "resources/css/scrollbar.css",
        "resources/css/datepicker.css",
        "resources/css/flaticon.css",
        "resources/css/notiflix.min.css",
        "resources/css/style.scss",
        "resources/css/override.scss",
        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        "resources/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
        "resources/js/popper.min.js",
        "resources/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "resources/js/magnific-popup.min.js",
        "resources/js/waypoints.min.js",
        "resources/js/counterup.min.js",
        "resources/js/waypoints-sticky.min.js",
        "resources/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
        "resources/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",
        "resources/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
        "resources/js/theia-sticky-sidebar.js",
        "resources/js/lc_lightbox.lite.js",
        "resources/js/bootstrap-select.min.js",
        "resources/js/dropzone.js",
        "resources/js/jquery.scrollbar.js",
        "resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
        "resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js",
        "resources/js/anm.js",
        "resources/js/notiflix.min.js",
        "resources/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
        "resources/js/chart.js",
        "resources/js/custom.js",
        "resources/js/app.js",
        "resources/js/init.js",
      ],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        { src: "resources/images", dest: "" },
        { src: "resources/fonts", dest: "" },
        { src: "resources/files", dest: "" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

I am not used to Vite.

Comment: In the error it says "Vite manifest not found at: E:\oblia\obilia_site\public\build/manifest.json". Notice all of them are backward slashes "\" except the one before "manifest.json". You should use backward slash as base.```{"base": "\"}}```

Comment: Let me know if this solves the issue. If it does, i will post this as answer

Comment: it should not be looking in 'public/build' dir because i changed it to 'public'. backslash and forward slash is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the outDir at the Laravel side of things as well.

After digging through the source code I found `Illuminate/Foundation/Vite::useBuildDirectory`  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6939c04d81abdbed300aba08208fcf88b37e3889/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php#L192
This is likely what you missed in configuring the new build directory.

The manifest is expected to be found at `public_path($buildDirectory.'/'.$this->manifestFilename);` with `$buildDirectory` having a default of `build`, and `$this->manifestFilename` a default of `manifest.json`. so thats how your `E:\oblia\obilia_site\public\build/manifest.json` came to be, with `E:\oblia\obilia_site\public` being your (default) public path.

If you configure the `$buildDirectory` as "." everything should work out.
You can find an example of how these things can be done in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#advanced-customization) under advanced customization in Vite.

The following code should do the trick instead of the `@vite` directive inside of your main template

```php
{{ Vite::useBuildDirectory('.') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have many layout HTML templates, we can either create a partial with the `Vite::useBuildDirectory` directive inside, or we can change the `build` directory globally inside `AppServiceProvider`.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Vite::useBuildDirectory('.');
    }
}
```